# connect to specific asterisk instance CLI

Tags: asterisk, pbx

On a centos dedicated server,

I'm running two asterisk instances on different bind IPs.

when I do

> asterisk -r

It connects to default asterisk instance which was started first.

I have tried :

> asterisk -r -s NEW_IP_OF_SECOND_INSTANCE:5060

It gives unable to connect.

But IP and port are both correct. netstat shows listening ports.

How to I connect to that second asterisk instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-s` option is used to specify Asterisk socket file (like `/var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl`). If you have multiple Asterisk instances running on one server, use this option with appropriate `asterisk.ctl` file.

5060 is a SIP port number, used to originate and receive VoIP calls rather than for management purposes, so you can't use it with `asterisk -r` command

Comment: Perfect. 

>asterisk -h shows "
   -s <socket>     Connect to Asterisk via socket <socket> (only valid with -r)
" so I thought like that socket.